# Why is this Regular Expression allowing an asterisk to pass?

Tags: regex

I have an odd phone validation that I need to do. The below pattern is working nicely for the rules I need to validate, but for some reason asterisks are being allowed to pass.

```
^(?=.{10,15}$)[\(\)-. ]*?([0-9]{3})[\(\)-. ]*?([0-9]{3})[\(\)-. ]*?([0-9]{4})
```

I have been using this site to test my expression: http://regexpal.com/

These are the values I need to pass:

- (501) 555 1234
- (501)-555.1234
- 501-555-1234
- 501.555.1234
- 501 555 1234
- 501) 343-2233
- (501 343-2233
- (501. 343-2233
- 5013432233
- 800-..555-1234
- -(.8005551234

These are the values I need to fail:

- *-(.8005551234
- 501*555-1234
- -(.80055512 41
- 501_555_1234
- 555-1234
- 800-...........555-1234
- 013432233

The rules are:

1. The string must be 10-15 total characters in length.
2. Must contain exactly 10 digits within string.
3. Can contain "(", ")" , " ", ".", or "-" delimiters within the string.
4. It doesn't matter how many delimiters are grouped as long as numbers are grouped in {3}{3}{4}.

So two questions:

1. **What do I need change to eliminate asterisks from passing?**
2. **What can I do to optimize this regular expression?**

Comment: 1. Escape the dashes within the square brackets: `-` -> `\-`.

Comment: That does it @idleherb. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do I need change to eliminate asterisks from passing?

You'll need to escape the dash in [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). If not escaped, it does denote a range - in your case, `\)-.` is equivalent to `)*+,-.`.

> What can I do to optimize this regular expression?

I assume you mean "simplify". I can see that the sequence `[\(\)-. ]*?([0-9]{3})` is repeated thrice, so if you don't care for the matching groups then I'd rather use

```
^(?=.{10,15}$)([\(\)\-. ]*?[0-9]{3}){3}[0-9]
```

You might also shorten `[0-9]` to `\d`.

Comment: Thank you for your time, answer, and explanation of how to fail the asterisks, but the regular expression you have posted does not appear to work for me.

Comment: @Bazinga: It [does fine here](https://regex101.com/r/kR1eB6/1). What doesn't work, what regex flavour / language are you using?

Comment: It looks good now. I copied it over earlier and was getting an oddly placed "(".

Comment: @Bazinga: Oh right, i fixed that in the edit grace period still. didn't think anyone would notice :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the optimized regex: `^(?=.{10,15}$)(?=.*(?:.*[0-9]){10}.*$)([()\s.-]*[0-9]{3}[()\s.-]*[0-9]{3}[()\s.-]*[0-9]{4})$`.

Or even more simplification: `^(?=.{10,15}$)(?:[()\s.-]*[0-9]{3}){3}[0-9]$`

Do not forget the anchors (`^` line start and `$` line end), and use multiline option. In JavaScript, it will be `/m`: `/^(?=.{10,15}$)(?:[()\s.-]*[0-9]{3}){3}[0-9]$/m`

And here is [a demo](https://regex101.com/r/kP2mE1/3).